# Weird dmesg Errors, Perhaps causing the Lag?

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, pop-os, troubleshooting, dmesg

I have some lag on my system that acts like a memory leak. Overtime, especially with repetitive suspends, my system can become unusable. Even shutting it down can take 15~20min if i don't hardshut it down. The memory usage however always seems fine, and I ran a memtest overnight and it's passing.

However, I did notice my dmesg logs had some errors i've never seen before. And the curious google search isn't helping me all that much unfortunately. Could this be the cause of my issues?

```
    [   13.216699] kernel: EDAC sbridge: Seeking for: PCI ID 8086:6faf
    [   13.216723] kernel: EDAC sbridge: CPU SrcID #0, Ha #0, Channel #0 has DIMMs, but ECC is disabled
    [   13.216778] kernel: EDAC sbridge: Couldn't find mci handler
    [   13.216823] kernel: EDAC sbridge: Failed to register device with error -19.
    [   13.387655] kernel: Dynamic Preempt: full
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those messages are innocuous. The EDAC messages are telling you that you don’t have ECC memory, which is probably expected. The dynamic preemption message is shown [on recent kernels where preemption can be chosen at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553993/86440), to confirm the chosen preemption mode (or the default).